# Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA) : Dependency package foreach not available

Tags: r

I am writing an R package for myself and this package depends on several existed packages. When I include package `foreach` in the `Depends` of the DESCRIPTION file like

```
Depends: R (>= 3.1.2), parallel, foreach, Rtsne, igraph
```

I would get an error message:

```
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA)  : 
Dependency package foreach not available.
```

when I use functions `document` or `load_all`.
But when I exclude `foreach` like

```
Depends: R (>= 3.1.2), parallel, Rtsne, igraph
```

everything goes well.

As package `foreach` is the only one going wrong, I am very confused now. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Same problem with different dependency, anyone knows the answer?